# cannot get the folder last modified time

Tags: perl

I want to get the folder last modified date and time through perl. My code is:

```
my @dirs = grep { -d } glob "$SOME_DIR/*";
foreach my $dir (@dirs)
{
    print($dir);
    print((stat $dir)[9]);  #line got problem with
}
```

But it just printed nothing but the sub foders under $SOME_DIR. I am SURE the $SOME_DIR path exists since the print($dir) works. Would anyone know what cant get the last modified time of a directory? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what `$SOME_DIR` looks like and what your output looks like?  I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you look into `$!` after the failing `stat()` call?

Comment: I got it, Thanks everyone. After remove use File::stat, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, with `$SOME_DIR = ".";`, I got the output:

```
./c-vs-c++1369283477./computist-1.dSYM1381934424./computist-2.dSYM1381934897./ll3.dSYM1381816690./syncio.dSYM1381984813./xs.dSYM1381986208
```

This mildy revised code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $SOME_DIR = ".";

my @dirs = grep { -d } glob "$SOME_DIR/*";
foreach my $dir (@dirs)
{
    printf "%-20s - %d\n", $dir, (stat $dir)[9];
}
```

gave the output:

```
./c-vs-c++           - 1369283477
./computist-1.dSYM   - 1381934424
./computist-2.dSYM   - 1381934897
./ll3.dSYM           - 1381816690
./syncio.dSYM        - 1381984813
./xs.dSYM            - 1381986208
```

You need to demonstrate what is in your `$SOME_DIR`.  For example, you might use:

```
system "ls -l $SOME_DIR";
```

to show what you should be seeing.

Comment: I got the list of sub folders under my $SOME_DIR:fullDate1, fullDate2, fullDate3

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use `my @dirs = glob "$SOME_DIR/*/"`, or does that not work on all operating systems?

Comment: Quite possibly...I was mostly demonstrating that the code described in the question could work by creating an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  The problem appears to have been the use of [`File::stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/stat.html).  The `grep` finds the directories (the `-d` test).  Otherwise the tests will need to be done in the body of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl

    @1=`ls -ltr abcdpathtodir | grep ^d | awk '{\$1=\$2=\$3=\$4=\$5=""; print \$0}'`;
    foreach $i (@1)
    {
            print " ---$i\n";
    }
```

or other way:-

```
@m=`ls -ltr dir | grep ^d | awk '{print \$6,\$7,\$8,\$9}'`;
foreach $i (@m)
{
        print "$i\n";

}
```

Comment: Using numbers as array names, and depending on shell commands makes sense when scripting in bash and similar, but in perl it is unnecessary dependency.

Comment: thanks for your comment ...as far as number as array name is considered we can change but for this case the shell commands works fine...do u have any solution with such short length of code i will be very happy to learn from that.......

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/19418840/223226 It uses perl native `glob()` for directory listing, filters directories with `-d` and `stat()` to get modification time